# Q: Compiler Error of linked list, but still runs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am not sure why I am getting these errors, but the weirdest thing, I am still able to run the program and produce the results I want.

The compiler error I get is

> IntelliSense: a value of type "MyStruct *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Mystuct_struct *"

There are 4 instances of this, but as I stated in my title, the program still seems to run fine, and displays the bin file as I want it to. And yes, I know the name of my structure is bad.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


typedef struct MyStruct_struct

{
  char FlightNum[7];
  char OriginAirportCode[5];
  char DestAirportCode[5];
  int timeStamp;
  struct Mystruct_struct* next;
} MyStruct;

int main()
{
  time_t time;
  MyStruct * ptr;
  MyStruct *  head; 
  MyStruct * tail;
  MyStruct * temp;
  FILE * bin;
  MyStruct myStruct;

  bin = fopen("acars.bin", "rb");
  ptr= (struct MyStruct_struct *) malloc (sizeof(MyStruct) );    
  fread(ptr,sizeof(MyStruct)-sizeof(MyStruct*),1,bin); 

  head = ptr; // make head point to that struct
  tail = ptr; // make tail point to that struct

  while (1) 
    {
      ptr = (struct MyStruct_struct *) malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)); 
      fread(ptr, sizeof(MyStruct) - sizeof(MyStruct*), 1, bin); 
      tail->next = ptr; // error here
      tail = tail->next; //error here

      if (feof(bin) != 0)
        break;




    }
  tail->next = NULL;

  ptr = head;
  while (ptr->next != NULL) 
    {

      printf("%s ", ptr->FlightNum);
      printf("%s ", ptr->OriginAirportCode);
      printf("%s ", ptr->DestAirportCode);
      time = ptr->timeStamp;
      printf("%s",ctime( &time));
      ptr = ptr->next; // here
    }

  ptr = head;
  while (ptr->next != NULL) 
    {

      temp = ptr;

      ptr = ptr->next; //error here
      free(temp);
    }


  fclose(bin);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Warnings or errors? 2) Are you sure it's running your latest version or the last successful compile? 3) Please fix the formatting so your code is readable.

Comment: Is the typo in your question a real typo or the problem? In you question, the error message says "Mystuct_struct" (the first "r" is missing).  Also, save the people who may have to maintain your code and don't have variable labels match the variabl type and differ only by case.  It is just mean.

Comment: Errors, not warnings. And yes, it is running the latest version. See: http://imgur.com/1Ga1I8T

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your struct definition.  The type for your variable next is MyStuct_Struct.   Check your spelling on MyStuct_Struct.  It still works because C is joiously not type safe.  A pointer is a pointer is a pointer so you don't end up with memory errors.

Comment: Thank you! But it still produces the same error:   10 IntelliSense: a value of type "Mystruct_struct *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "MyStruct *"

Comment: Ok, so my C skills are a bit rusty, but after looking at the screenshot of the warning, I think I got it.  In the struct definition, next is of type MyStruct_Struct*.  The type for ptr is MyStruct*.  In line 38, tail->next gets prt (you assign a MyStruct* to a MyStruct_Strict*).  Then the other three errors are the reverse, you assign tail->next to tail (also of type MyStruct*). Change everything ( the initial variable definitions ) to MyStruct_Struct and it should work ok.